# How to Called Resetting Array Index to Beginning

Tags: arrays, c, indexing

How can we called resetting array index to beginning for clearing that array? I mean we are not clearing that array by setting 0 (zero).

When we reset the array index to beginning of that array, when new data come, we will write to old data which is located in the beginning of the array. What is the name of this type of resetting in terminology?

Best regards,
Mert.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C are not “reset.” An array in C is simply memory that can hold values. (Specifically contiguous memory for elements of a particular type.) It does not have any extra data about which elements have been set or reset or which are in use or not. The only “clearing” operation for an array is to set its elements to the value zero, or to some other value you might choose to have “cleared” meaning for you.

Just as an array does not have any extra data about which elements have been set or reset, it does not have any index associated with it. To index an array, you maintain your own variables containing whatever indices you want. If you want to track how many elements of an array are in use by your program, you make your own variable to hold that number. (Novice C programmers often use an `int` variable for that. Experienced programmers may prefer the unsigned type `size_t` or the signed type `ptrdiff_t`, both of which are declared in `<stddef.h>`.)

To reset your index to the beginning of the array, you simply set your index to zero.